# Why do I get two files in my upload temp folder?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, ajaxform

I use PHP in a form to upload files. But I get two files in windows temp (I use IIS). But When I move the file I get one file.

html

```
<form id="order-form" class="needs-validation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<!-- about 20 input fields --> 
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Send order</button>
                                        <div id="send-information">
                                            <small><span id="procent">0%</span> complete or <span id="loaded">0</span> of <span id="file-size">0</span></small>
                                            <div class="progress">
                                                <div id="progressNumber" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Ajax file upload

```
    function fileSelected() {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    
        if (file) {
            var fileSize = 0;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            else
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
            
            document.getElementById('file-size').innerHTML = fileSize;
        }
    }
    
    function uploadFile(fd) {
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        
        // stop the non-ajax form post
        fd.preventDefault();
        
        xhr.open("POST", "src/fileUpload.php");
        xhr.send(fd);
    }
    
    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            
            //var loaded = 0;
            if (evt.loaded > 1024 * 1024)
            loaded = (Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            else
            loaded = (Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
            
            document.getElementById('procent').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').style.width = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
            
            document.getElementById('loaded').innerHTML = loaded.toString();
            
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
    }
    
    function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
        window.location.replace("src/successpage.html");
    }
    
    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }
    
    function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    }

and my PHP file upload in fileUpload.php

    <?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */
        
        //$fileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; // The file name
        $fileName = $_SESSION['fileName'];
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
        $fileType = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
        $fileSize = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
        
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../uploads/$fileName")
    ?>
```

../uploads have one file but windows temp have two temp files for the uploaded file.

Send the order. sendOrder.php picks up all the fields expect the file upload and send them in a email.

```
//Send order form
$('#order-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'src/sendOrder.php',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        cache: false
    });
    uploadFile(formData);
})
```

Comment: `fd.preventDefault();` – `fd` is your FormData object here, calling `preventDefault` on that makes no sense, and should get you an error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You get two files because you do request `src/sendOrder.php` twice. First time you do it in ajax request (last code block in your post), second time is when you call function `uploadFiles(formData)` after ajax request.

You should try to exclude $.ajax(...) from last code block. Or exclude `uploadFiles(formData)`, but progress bar will not work.